# How can unification be applied to interaction combinators?

Tags: pl.programming-languages

The problem of unifying interaction combinators is probably undecidable since those are turing complete. As opposed to the lambda calculus, there is nothing like a simple type theory for interaction combinators nor a subproblem of them that is known to be decidable.

When is it possible to unify interaction combinators?